# Scala ant build error

Tags: scala, playframework, ant

I have a Scala project, I am writing build.xml to build it using ant. I am using play 1.2.7 and scala-2.10.4 in my ubuntu environment. Follwoing is my build.xml

Ant file for building the Ipp Partner application for JBoss 5.0.1 on DIT

```
<!-- release build settings -->
<property name="dist.dir" value="${java.io.tmpdir}/dist"/>
<property name="partner.dist.template" value="deployment/partner-domain"/>
<property name="partner.war.dir" value="${build.dir}/partner/partner.war"/>
<property name="partner.sql.dir.source" value="sql"/>
<property name="partner.sql.dir.migrations" value="${partner.sql.dir.source}/migrations"/>
<property name="partner.docs.dir.source" value="documentation"/>
<property name="partner.sql.dir.dest" value="${dist.dir}/resources/sql"/>
<property name="partner.sql.dir.dest.migrations" value="${dist.dir}/resources/sql/migrations"/>
<property name="partner.docs.dir.dest" value="${dist.dir}/docs"/>
<property name="partner.translations.dir.dest" value="${dist.dir}/resources/translations/"/>
<property name="partner.doc.dir" value="documentation"/>
<property name="dist.partner.war.dir" value="${dist.dir}/applications/partner.ear/partner.war"/>
<property name="lib" value="lib"/>
<tstamp>
    <format property="dist.time" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm"/>
</tstamp>


<target name="init">
    <property
    name="scala-library.jar"
    value="${env.SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-library.jar"
     />
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${lib}/anorm_2.10-2.3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/bootstrap-3.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/play-1.2.7.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/play-ws_2.10-2.3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/webjars-play_2.10-2.3.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/sbt-plugin-2.3.1.jar"/>



        <fileset dir="${env.PLAY_HOME}/framework">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${env.PLAY_HOME}/framework/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${env.PLAY_HOME}/modules/scala-0.9/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>

        <pathelement location="${scala-library.jar}"   />
        <pathelement location="${env.PLAY_HOME}/framework/play-1.2.7.jar"/>
        <!--<pathelement location="${your.path}"   />-->
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"   />
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${env.SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-compiler.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${env.SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-reflect.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${scala-library.jar}"/>
            <pathelement location="${env.PLAY_HOME}/framework/play-1.2.7.jar"/>




            <pathelement location="${lib}/anorm_2.10-2.3.1.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/bootstrap-3.2.0.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/play-1.2.7.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/play-ws_2.10-2.3.1.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/webjars-play_2.10-2.3.0.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/sbt-plugin-2.3.1.jar"/>

        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
</target>

<target name="build" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <echo>build.dir:  ${build.dir}</echo>
    <scalac srcdir="/home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner"
            destdir="${build.dir}"
            classpathref="build.classpath">
    </scalac>
</target>
```

and following is my imports in the scala files:

```
import play.api._
import models._
import anorm._
import play.api.mvc.Filter
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.mvc.Result
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.mvc.SimpleResult
import play.api.mvc.WithFilters
import play.Configuration
import filter.UrlRewritingFilter
import play.api.libs.Crypto
```

After build I am getting following error messages:

```
[scalac] Compiling 49 scala and 2 java source files to /tmp/build
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:4: error: object mvc is not a member of package play.api
   [scalac] import play.api.mvc.Filter
   [scalac]                 ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:5: error: object mvc is not a member of package play.api
   [scalac] import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
   [scalac]                 ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:6: error: object mvc is not a member of package play.api
   [scalac] import play.api.mvc.Result
   [scalac]                 ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:8: error: object mvc is not a member of package play.api
   [scalac] import play.api.mvc.SimpleResult
   [scalac]                 ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:9: error: object mvc is not a member of package play.api
   [scalac] import play.api.mvc.WithFilters
   [scalac]                 ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:10: error: object Configuration is not a member of package play
   [scalac] import play.Configuration
   [scalac]        ^
   [scalac] /home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/app/Global.scala:12: error: object Crypto is not a member of package play.api.libs
   [scalac] import play.api.libs.Crypto
   [scalac]        ^
```

Can anyone please guide me how to fix these issues. I already had added play dependencies in the class path but still why I am getting these play errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting play error in the Scala ant build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807161/getting-play-error-in-the-scala-ant-build)

Comment: There is no soln available for the previous one. Can anyone please help with some solution?

Comment: Check your classpath in the compilation task.

Comment: I did not get your point, Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Can you please post the complete build script? have you defined `env`? Since it is not able find the `import`'s meaning that the dependencies are not in classpath.

Comment: I added the whole script. Please check.